# Using XPath to extract elements from a specific location in the document

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML document and a number of paths I can use to extract data from it.

Example paths:

```
Bill/Id 
Bill/Line/AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail
```

The tricky part is that I need to extract each data point from the same "region" of the document. For example, if I was given a document like this:

```
        <Bill domain="QBO" sparse="false">
            <Line>
                <AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
                    1
                </AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
            </Line>
        </Bill>
        <Bill domain="QBO" sparse="false">
            <Id>148</Id>
        </Bill>
```

I would actually need to return nothing given the paths above, since the `<AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>` and `<Id>` tags are found within different `<Bill>` tags.

However, if the document looked like this:

```
            <Bill domain="QBO" sparse="false">
                <Id>148</Id>
                <Line>
                     <AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
                       1
                     </AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
                 </Line>
            </Bill>
```

I would return 148 for the `Bill\Id` path and 1 for the `Bill/Line/AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail` path, since they're both contained in the same `Bill` object.

This is pretty tricky since the requirement holds for more complex tables as well with deeply nested objects. Is there some XPath functionality I'm missing that might make this problem a bit easier? As it stands right now I can think of a fairly complex recursive solution, but I don't want to start working on it if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/Bill[Line/AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail]/Id
```

will return the `Id` element only if `Bill` has an `Line` child element which itself has a `AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail` child element.

and this XPath,

```
/Bill[Id]/Line/AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail
```

will return the `AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail` element only if `Bill` has an `Id` child element.